# How to Make Very Simple ASP.Net Password Protected Page

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am looking for a very simple solution to password protect an ASP.Net page.

I found exactly what I am looking for [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301464) but it is in ASP and I do not know the syntax to convert it to ASP.Net.

It simply creates a temporary cookie that will expire as soon as they close their browser window.

I am not looking to store the username / password in a db. I will manually change the password occasionally.

Simply helping me convert the following code to ASP.Net would be wonderful!

This goes on the logon.aspx page and pulls values from a form.

```
Username="Administrator"
Password="Admin"
Validated = "OK"

if Strcomp(Request.Form("User"),Username,1)=0 AND Request.Form("password") = Password then
    Response.Cookies("ValidUser") = Validated

    If (Request.QueryString("from")<>"") then
        Response.Redirect Request.QueryString("from")
    else
      Response.Redirect "MyPage.aspx"
    End if    
Else
    If Request.Form("User") <> "" then
        Response.Write "<h3>Authorization Failed.</h3>" & "<br>" & _ "Please try again.<br>&#xa0;<br>"
    End if
End if
```

This goes on the password protected page to confirm the cookie was created.

```
Validated = "OK"

if Request.Cookies("ValidUser") <> Validated then
dim s
s = "http://"
s = s & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")
s = s & Request.ServerVariables("URL")

if Request.QueryString.Count > 0 THEN
    s = s & "?" & Request.QueryString 
end if

Response.Redirect "Logon.aspx"
End if
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the built-in forms authentication and setup your credentials store in the web.config.

[Here's a quick and dirty example](http://web.archive.org/web/20110422125029/http://15seconds.com/issue/020220.htm)

[Another example](https://web.archive.org/web/20120423031304/http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/01/06/formsauthp1.html)

Comment: Thanks Eric. Is there an easy way to avoid the "sign out" button and have the authentication cookie expire on window close like above?

Comment: Yes. That is the default behavior of authentication cookies.

Comment: Cool, so I can just remove the "sign out" button and it will default to cookie expiration?

Comment: Sure? The way Forms authentication works by default, is you will remain signed-in until a) the SignOut() method is called (usually invoked by clicking a "Sign Out" link or button, or b) the user closes their browser window in which the case the ticket automatically expires. You could remove the Sign Out button all together, that's up to you. I think if you glance over those links I provided, it will become clear what needs to be done. It really is quite simple.